# An error about the Flask-Socket IO: when the client connects to the server,it continually throw the 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, flask, websocket

I want to achieve the websocket between the frontend and backend,and i find the example in the internet,but
when i run the code,it always throws the 400 error.
This is the flask server code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret_key'

socketio = SocketIO()
socketio.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')

name_space = '/dcenter'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/push')
def push_once():
    event_name = 'dcenter'
    broadcasted_data = {'data': "test message!"}
    socketio.emit(event_name, broadcasted_data, broadcast=False, namespace=name_space)
    return 'done!'


@socketio.on('connect', namespace=name_space)
def connected_msg():
    print('client connected.')


@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace=name_space)
def disconnect_msg():
    print('client disconnected.')


@socketio.on('my_event', namespace=name_space)
def mtest_message(message):
    print(message)
    emit('my_response',
         {'data': message['data'], 'count': 1})


if __name__ == '__main__':

    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

This is the client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SocketIO Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.bootcss.com/socket.io/1.5.1/socket.io.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Demo of SocketIO</h2>
<div id="t"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    namespace = '/dcenter';
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
    socket.on('dcenter', function (res) {
        var t = res.data;
        if (t) {
            $("#t").append(t).append('<br/>');
        }

    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error message:
`"GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OQIAKtK HTTP/1.1" 400`

i try to change the version of flask-socketio and engine-io and find another example code, but it all failed.

Answer (score 0):

In your html file.

Version 1.5.1. for socket.io.min.js is to old:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.bootcss.com/socket.io/1.5.1/socket.io.min.js"></script>
```

You should use something newer like 4.5.4 instead:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js" ></script>
```

There are mainly 4 components with python which have to be compatible with each other. I use the following components/versions:

In the HTML file:

```
#version socket.io == 4.5.4
#more versions availabe here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js" ></script>
```

Packages:

```
Flask-SocketIO == 5.3.2
python-engingeio == 4.3.4
python-socketio == 5.7.2
```

Below an overview for the versions from:

[https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#:~:text=Flask%2DSocketIO%20is%20compatible%20with,a%20number%20of%20different%20configurations](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#:%7E:text=Flask%2DSocketIO%20is%20compatible%20with,a%20number%20of%20different%20configurations).

[image]

Comment: thank you.In my html file,the socket io version is too old,i upgrade version as you provide,it finally works